# No such file or directory ... /meteor/examples

Tags: node.js, macos, meteor

I am trying to create a new project using Meteor but am getting this message:

```
user$ meteor create testProject1

fs.js:665
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor/examples'
at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:665:18)
at Object.Commands.push.func (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:156:32)
at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:631:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteor/app/meteor/meteor.js:634:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Any ideas on what's wrong and/or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered with this problem and found this question while looking for the answer.

The error appeared when I tried to use the meteor from npm:

```
npm uninstall -g meteor
```

Installed it from their server as indicated in their official site:

```
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

And the problem was solved

Comment: Worked for me! Was having lots of weird problems. Also realized I didn't have Xcode installed (OS X), which apparently is good to have for installations such as these! It fixed some errors in npm install -g meteor before I gave this a try. But this is the final thing that fixed it.

Comment: @timothyashaw great! Glad to have helped

Comment: It appears the package isn't really meteor https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1721#issuecomment-31329080

Comment: As a Windows user I am quite happy about this answer.